# Get the last error message thrown for an instruction

Tags: f#, parsec, fparsec

I noticed that the error messages sent by FParsec were quite "ambiguous", except for the last message sent for an instruction.
Here is an example:

Code to parse:

```
if (2 + 2 == 4)
```

Here, normally, there should be an instruction block (so in brackets).

And what I get:

> Failure: Error in Ln: 1 Col: 1 if (2 + 2 == 4) ^ Expecting: [some instructions]
>
> The parser backtracked after:   Error in Ln: 1 Col: 3   if (2 + 2 ==
>   4)
>       ^   Bad identifier: 'if' is a reserved keyword
>
> The parser backtracked after:   Error in Ln: 1 Col: 16   if (2 + 2 ==
>   4)
>                    ^   Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream.   Expecting: start block

As you can see, only the last error message is relevant. So I would like to know if there is not a way to display only this one, and therefore the last one without going through the others.
I guess it's not easy, since it's a feature of FParsec, but you never know...

I don't think I need to post F# code, since it's usually in the use of the library.

**Edit**

Here is the code of my analyzer to parse the example above:

```
type Statement =
    | If of Expr * Block option
    // And others...
and Block = Block of Statement list

let ws = pspaces >>. many pspaces |>> (fun _ -> ())
let str_ws s = pstring s .>> ws

let pexpr, pexprimpl = createParserForwardedToRef ()
    // With their implementations (addition, subtraction, ...)

let pstatement, pstatementimpl = createParserForwardedToRef ()
    // With their implementations, like "pif" below
let psinglestatement = pstatement |>> fun statement -> [statement]

let pstatementblock =
    psinglestatement <|>
    between (ws >>. str_ws "{") (ws >>. str_ws "}") (many pstatement)

let pif =
    pipe2
        (str_ws "if" >>. pexpr)
        (pstatementblock)
        (fun cnd block -> If(cnd, Some (Block(block))))

pstatementimpl :=
    attempt (pif) <|>
    // And others...
```

**Edit II:**

Here is the code of identifier analyse:

```
let reserved = [ 
                    "if"; "else" // And other...
               ]

let pidentifierraw =
    let inline isIdentifierFirstChar c = isLetter c
    let inline isIdentifierChar c = isLetter c || isDigit c
    many1Satisfy2L isIdentifierFirstChar isIdentifierChar "identifier"

let pidentifier =
    pidentifierraw
    >>= fun s ->
        if reserved |> List.exists ((=) s) then fail ("Bad identifier: '" + s + "' is a reserved keyword")
        else preturn s

type Literal = 
    | Identifier of string
    // And other...

let pid = pidentifier |>> Literal.Identifier
```

`pexpr` is a set of values, including identifiers, literals, and their operations:

```
let pexpr, pexprimpl = createParserForwardedToRef ()
type Assoc = Associativity

let opp = OperatorPrecedenceParser<Expr, unit, unit> ()
pexprimpl := opp.ExpressionParser <?> "expression"
let term = pvalue .>> ws <|> between (str_ws "(") (str_ws ")") pexpr
opp.TermParser <- term
let inops   = [ "+"; "-"; "*"; "/"; "=="; "!="; "<="; ">="; "<"; ">" ]

for op in inops do opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator(op, ws, 1, Assoc.Left, fun x y -> InfixOp(x, op, y)))
```

`pvalue` defines literals, including identifiers with `pidentifier`. I don't think I need to put their definitions, since they all follow this pattern (for example):

```
let ptrue   = str_ws "true"  |>> fun _ -> Bool(true)
let pfalse  = str_ws "false" |>> fun _ -> Bool(false)
let pbool   = ptrue <|> pfalse
```

Comment: The way errors are reported depends on how you've structured your parser. I think it would be helpful to show your code.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin – I edited the post.

Comment: I don't see the part the produces the "bad identifier" error.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't think that was really necessary. I don't think there's any other need.

Comment: Are you sure that `pstatementimpl` has `attempt (pif)` as the very first alternative?

Comment: No, it is not the case, I tested according to your criteria, but there is apparently no change.